# Available implementations of a distributed REST queue

Tags: http, rest, queue, distributed, distributed-computing

I have the following (common, I guess) scenario: a master node holding a list of items (urls, jobs, whatever) to be processed, and a set of N worker nodes.

Each worker pops an item from the queue, does something, then notifies the master node that the job has successfully finished.

A worker may push new items to the master node, for these to be queued for processing.

Requirements are quite simple:

- no job gets executed twice
- no job gets picked by two nodes (ie. "pop" is atomic)
- if a job fails, after a fixed timeout, the job is again available for processing
- the number of concurrent workers is potentially big
- several workers may live on a single node
- master and workers are not assumed to be in the same network
- pop and push must be exposed as a REST API (ie. the queue is language-agnostic)
- items must be stored persistently on the master node (ie. no in-memory solutions)

I am not able to find *simple* and lightweight REST implementations: I have looked at [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/), [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html) and a bunch of other less mature projects, but all of them seem quite complex to manage, and a bit like overkill for what I need.

Any solution that I might be overlooking?

Comment: And if you introduce the ability to have a job priority, then the candidate list shows like even more empty ....

Comment: Hi, How are you going with this?  I am in a similar situation and would be great if you share your story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the same search. I found celery was close (also looked at others like octobot) - none seemed as simple as I desired, and were missing a few things. I found celery was fairly simple, however introduces a reasonable amount of dependencies which I didn't already have in the mix, so I went with something bespoke instead (erlang based)

Comment: is it open source by any chance? :)

Answer (score 2):

Amazon SQS might be what you want: http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/

Jan

Comment: Thank you, this is a good alternative I was not aware of. I am mostly looking for something deployable on my machines though.